# Paging UIScrollView with "Prototype Pages"

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm trying to create a horizontal pager where I can swipe through "cards" of photos (which have an image, some caption text, and some action buttons). Here's a diagram:
[image]

I'm currently following this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift) which shows how to make paging `UIScrollView` where each page just displays a `UIImageView`, which they set up programmatically by just adding a `UIImageView` as a subview.

My interface of course has more than just a `UIImageView` and I want to make it a bit more complicated. My question is, **is there a way I can build a reusable "prototype page" through the Interface Builder in XCode?** In other words, can I set up a reusable page non-programmatically?

This is similar to how you can create a reusable prototype cell in Interface Builder for a `UITableView`. I'd like to know if there's a similar solution for horizontal pagers.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to add an animation where the user can move through the page, but the page remains the same and just refreshes the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UIPageViewController` and a `UIViewController` as a template and dynamically instantiate a template and use.

---

Alternatively, I've created another version that uses `UIScrollView` with `UIContainerView`'s to achieve (almost) the same result. [Sample Code](https://github.com/qalandarov/SwiftPagedScrollView)

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about `UIPageViewController` that seems useful for me. Thanks for that sample project too!

Comment: You're welcome! The **good** thing about `UIPageViewController` is that it does the memory management for you and creating an infinite scroller is easy. The **bad** thing is that it caches the `before` and `after` pages (in case if you dynamically change the previous/next pages)